# How to LPF only one of the inputs to a voltage adder?

Tags: noise, low-pass, integrator, summing

I'm taking voltages from two inputs, and I'd like to add them together using an op amp (this is actually a summing integrator).

[image]

I would like to filter out the noise in V_DAC (which will not change very often), without filtering the noise in V_TZA (which is the signal that I care about). If I put the capacitor where it is right now, V_DAC gets filtered, but so does V_TZA. I hear that putting C1 to the left side of R2 is a bad idea, because now the DAC has to drive a very capacitive load with its low-impedance output (I think this would make the noise worse, not better).

Some ideas that come to mind:

- some clever way of bootstrapping the noise from the DAC to one of the terminals of the op amp (I don't have a high-enough IQ to figure out how this would work on my own)
- making R2 a potentiometer T network, and putting C1 on the T, then tune the potentiometer until I get optimal performance.
- using some sort of buffer after the R2 C1 low-pass filter (V_DAC is already on the order of single-digit nV/√Hz, so I don't know if a buffer would help significantly)

Comment: If you use a buffer then you'll need a new "R2" between the buffer and the other opamp.

Comment: Why do you think that the opamp works as a"summing intergator"? The transfer function between the "+"input and output is H(s)=1+1/sRC

Comment: Your "integrator" is integrating ground (0V) while using a weighted average of V_DAC and V_TZA as its reference - that's not an integrator in any useful sense.

Comment: As a corollary to what @LvW said, if you need a summing integrator then you need the inverting configuration.

Comment: Using a buffer is the first thing that comes to mind (at the obvious cost of higher power dissipation). Can you clarify why you say in the last sentence that you "don't know if a buffer would help significantly"?

Comment: @Adam Q, If the DAC is already at single-digit nV per rtHz, putting a low pass filtered followed by another op amp with a noise of a few nV per rtHz simply removes noise and adds it back in again.

Comment: @Concerned citizen, why is that? Why can’t a non-inverting solution be used?

Answer (score 0):

Close, try this modification of your circuit:

[image]